# ¿Debo utilizar «decirle» o «decirles»?

Tags: verbos, coloquialismos

Estoy redactando un documento de adiestramiento y me encuentro con una duda sobre el uso de esta palabra. La oración es la siguiente:

> La idea es decirle a los integrantes qué se les va a presentar durante el día.

Yo pienso que debo utilizar «decirle», pero Microsoft Word me lo marca como error y me sugiere utilizar «decirles».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Microsoft Word* está en lo correcto.  El pronombre enclítico debe concordar aquí con el objeto indirecto ("los integrantes") y por lo tanto va en plural.

Sin embargo mi tendencia sería también a usar el singular (pues me suena mejor y más natural) pero no lo haría en un documento serio.

Comment: Aún mejor: no usar ningún enclítico. *La idea es decir a los integrantes*...

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el objeto indirecto está en plural, el verbo no necesita escribirse en plural pues no se trata de varias oraciones aunque el objeto indirecto sea plural y hasta puede ser impersonal, puede ser "decir" ejemplo: iré a decir a los miembros del equipo las reglas del juego.